# How to properly report an error from InvokableAction

Tags: visual-workflow, invocable-method

I'm creating an `InvokableAction` that should be ran as a part of the flow. This action has two string inputs, but one of them must accept only one of the three specific values. As far as I know, I can't have an `InvokableVariable` of enum type so I have to handle the values manually. What is the appropriate way to report incorrect values or even to report some other runtime errors? Throw an exception or return some error message as an output of this action?